# listing permissions

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, root

I'm a biomedical scientist and I'm having trouble running a custom data analysis pipeline written by one of our collaborators.  His script crashes with

```
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/local/bin/FastQC/FastQC_v0.10.1: Permission denied
make[2]: *** [/home/kat/gentrap.git/gentrap_OUT/1_Bira_TAAGGCGAGAGTAG_R1.fastqc] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/kat'
```

Thing is, I've already made myself the owner of `/usr/local/bin/FastQC` (`sudo chown -R user:user /usr/local/bin/FastQC`) and given myself read/write/executable permissions (`sudo chmod -R +rwx /usr/local/bin/FastQC`).  I tried listing permissions with `ls -la` and I'm a little confused by the output:

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 kat  kat  4096 mei  8 14:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 mei  8 14:20 ..
drwxr-xr-x 7 kat  kat  4096 mei  8 14:20 FastQC_v0.10.1
```

As I understand it, that means I'm the owner of the current directory and the subdirectory `FastQC_v0.10.1`, and I should have all the permissions.  Root is the owner of the parent directory, which would be `/usr/local/bin`.  Am I reading this output correctly?  Why would the script be crashing due to insufficient permissions?

Comment: run the script like this `sudo /path/script`

Comment: The script cannot be run that way.  I'm not sure if it technically can be called a script.  It is executed by "make -j 7 -f (a whole lot of flags)" in the installation directory.

Comment: Please show us the script. We can't help unless we know what it's trying to do.

Comment: I can't, it's proprietary, and I don't have their permission to post the source code.

I tried running it with sudo make blah blah, but then it crashes looking for a file attached to one of their repositories.  Probably because to install that repository, I had to edit .bashrc in my home directory, and the superuser probably has a different home directory.

If you can't help without seeing the source code, then I'll just have to wait for my collaborator to get back to me.

Comment: Is FastQC_v0.10.1 supposed to be a directory or a file?

Comment: OK in that case, you should ask your collaborator. The error you're getting implies you're trying to execute something that either isn't executable or that you don't have permissions to execute. Without knowing what it is that you're attempting to run, we can't help. You should be able to post just the relevant lines of the program, it's just a text file after all, not compiled code. I find it very hard to believe that your collaborator would mind. If he does, change your collaborator. The bioinformatics community thrives on open source.

Comment: FastQC_v0.10.1 is a directory.  The way the program works is that you supply the paths to various dependencies with flags, like "FASTQC_EXE=/home/user/bin/FastQC/fastqc".  I suspect the flags aren't working correctly, because the program crashed a couple of times looking for a file in blahblah/FastQC/FastQC_v0.10.1/executable, when the actual path was blahblah/FastQC/executable, and the flag was set correctly.

Comment: I'll ask him about what I am and am not allowed to share regarding source code, but his coding skills are much more sophisticated that mine, so I really don't want to upset him if I can avoid it.  I agree that bioinformatics tools should be open source, but it's not my decision to make.

Comment: In my professional experience (coming from work in the scientific computing community), wrapper scripts that compile binaries or start executables are rarely of concern to authors of proprietary code. The intellectual property worthy of protection is usually the source code of the underlying program to compile or execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error. I end up putting FastQC to `/usr/share`, as many other packages are put there, and put a link to `/usr/local/bin`, as suggested by the installation guide. Then I changed the permissions to files under `FastQC`.

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/FastQC/fastqc /usr/local/bin/fastqc
sudo chmod -R 755 /path/to/FastQC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `/usr/local/bin/FastQC` is a symlinked directory and since you said you already own it, then probably you may have to add the execute permission to the original location where the `fastqc` program is. Also note at what step the script crashes - is the script trying to create any files/directories at places you don't have permission to, etc..

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo chmod -R +rwx /usr/local/bin/FastQC
```

Should have set the read / write / execute flag to `/usr/local/bin/FastQC` and to its content for the owner, for the group and for the others, but from your `ls -la` output the group and the others are missing the write flag:

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 kat  kat  4096 mei  8 14:20 .
[...]
drwxr-xr-x 7 kat  kat  4096 mei  8 14:20 FastQC_v0.10.1
```

Altough this might not be a problem, it looks like `chmod` somehow failed.

The first thing I'd try would be to run `chmod -R +rwx /usr/local/bin/FastQC` again and check whether `/usr/local/bin/FastQC` and its inner folders / files (which might don't have the read / write / execute flags set for the owner already) are actually set to be read / written / executed by the owner.